# Special characters inside the value does not work with like operator while the same works with = operator in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2016

Can someone please help me find the issue with the value

```
City!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|:"<>?;''./[]\/*-+.
```

stored in a column which is firing the select query working fine with `=` operator but not working when using with the `LIKE` operator.

For example:

```
create table test_kee (some_column nvarchar(50));

insert into test_kee 
values ('City!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|:"<>?;''./[]\/*-+.');
```

This query is working fine:

```
 select * 
 from test_kee 
 where some_column = 'City!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|:"<>?;''./[]\/*-+.';
```

but this query is not working:

```
 select * 
 from test_kee 
 where some_column like '%City!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|:"<>?;''./[]\/*-+.%';
```

Comment: Hopefully, there will come a day when I wont feel the need to upvote an SQL question just because it provides proper sample data, but it is not this day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chars `[`. `]`, `%` and `_` have special meanings with the `like` operator.
You need to handle them differently if you are using the `like` operator.
Specifically, you need to escape them using a char you then specify in the `escape` clause:

```
select * 
from test_kee 
where some_column like '%City!@#$~%^&*()~_+-={}|:"<>?;''./~[~]\/*-+.%' escape '~';
```

More details are available in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)